# Selfmade hand sanitizer?

Tags: proximity-sensor, solenoid-valve

I want to build a hand sanitizer on my own. Like these, you can buy for enormous prices.

I need a proximity sensor (like the ones, which use infrared to check if someone is there).

And I need a small (!) valve to dispense a few milliliters (!) of the liquid (I found valves, which can pass dozens of liters per minute, that is too much). It will be a liquid comparable to water. I do not need a pump (gravity will do the trick), so I do not have a lot of pressure to open a valve. Would be great, if this valve can run on 3 or 5 V, so I can power the whole thing with a few batteries. If this valve is silent, would be even better.

I think, I will not use any microcontroller for that, just a few basic components like resistors, transistors and such stuff.

Any ideas for the proximity sensor and the valve? Did not find anything so far....

EDIT: I do not want a recommendation, where to get these things. But, searching on Google did not give me any usable results. My question is more like "Do you know an IC, which I can use for a timer" -> NE555. I am not searching for a specific product.

So my problem is: How can I open a tank for a short period of time? I do not need a pump, but I do not have a lot of pressure to open a valve.

To get a proximity sensor is the easier part of the problem.

Comment: Site rules: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.* Apart from that, given that you are dispensing something that cleans your hands I think that making it work contactless is far over-the-top.

Comment: Press the manual dispenser with your elbow.

Comment: A foot control...

Comment: There are such dispensers already located in hospitals everywhere. (Often, quite stupidly, located above a sink's faucet handle so that every time you reach to turn on the faucet the darned thing dumps sanitizer onto the back of your hand and arm.) They do everything you want, exactly the way you want, including a bag at top, a valve between, choice of nozzle outputs, etc. Just go find the schematic for one. Or tear one of them apart and look for yourself. All the hard work has been done for you. Just copy it, study it, reduce it if appropriate, and build it. Then write up a web page on it.

Comment: @ SolarMike

@ Transistor

I do not want other people to touch it, so I want to use a proximity sensor.

@ jonk Great idea! But the problem is, that these are costly, and I do not have one to disassemble. So my idea was, to build my own. The only real problem is the valve.

@ Andyaka see my edit, and answer me the following: Where should I ask for such things, if not here? Why are contactless systems sold, if the are not needed in your eyes?

Comment: Why are foot controls sold, if they are not needed in your eyes?

Comment: If you want to ping someone you need to use the syntax `@username` with no spaces. I think you can only ping one person per comment.

Comment: @SolarMike, isn't a foot control hugely impractical to install and use compared to an IR proximity detector? The latter is used in public toilets all over the place, the former not since the 70s.

Comment: @TonyM Not since the '70s? Amazon has them, surprised they consider carrying **such** old stoick: https://www.amazon.com/Mallofusa-Floor-Mounted-Singe-Silver/dp/B0791F83RR/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=foot+tap+control&qid=1601222676&sr=8-2

Comment: @SolarMike, I'm afraid you're replying what I didn't say. Foot controls haven't been used in public toilets all over the place since the 70s or so. But what about "isn't a foot control hugely impractical to install and use compared to an IR proximity detector?" i.e. the IR sensors used in public toilets all over the place?

Comment: @TonyM why are you so fixated on public toilets?The Op dies not mention them...

Comment: Well, I want to install them in a more or less public place (but not on a toilet).

Comment: @SolarMike, you mean what made me read your idea and think of toilets?

Comment: @TonyM I thought of professional kitchens with large sinks but your mind takes you where you wish...

Comment: What, pro kitchens with The Devil's Work: lovely IR sensors? They could be pump-action light sensors, might be less...alarming. Anyway, how can someone called @SolarMike not like light sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned options for the sensing.

A simple option for the dispensing would be the use of a [peristaltic pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristaltic_pump) driven by a stepper motor.

Each half rotation of a peristaltic pump will give an amount of fluid which is largely consistent each time. The amount is related to the cross sectional area of the pumping tube, and the diameter of the pumping head.

The nice thing about these pumps is that they can work with gels as easily as fluids (I used one to pump epoxy potting compound at one point). Furthermore, when the pump is not spinning, you get no flow through the pump (as its effectively self sealing). You can also make one yourself relatively easily (its just a piece of tube, a cylinder and a rotating rubber head).

By using a stepper motor, you can perform a half rotation, or a full rotation if you want more. That will give you a certain number of units of measure. Then stop.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas for the proximity sensor and the valve? Did not find anything so far....

For battery powered, you will probably want to use a PIR (passive IR sensor).  These are a photodiode and a high pass filter used to detect changes in illumination.  Differential PIR can also be used so that things like changes in illumination do not trigger the sensor, but an object moving between the sensors or across their field of view will.

These are commonly used in outdoor lighting, security sensors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The big question is, is this powered from a wall socket, or do you require battery power?

I'll assume the former.

For a proximity sensor, an IR LED and a photodiode (or even another LED) will work. Mount the two side by side. Use AC to drive the LED, and look for a matching frequency on the detector output. I warn you that you'll need at least a few transistors, and an op amp or two will give you much better results.

A PIR, such as suggested by user1850479 will work better, and is the sensor of choice if you're using battery power.

You don't need a valve, particularly since your sanitizer is the consistency of water and will flow freely.

Connect your sanitizer tank to the dispenser nozzle using a length of thin-walled rubber tubing. Use a spring-loaded solenoid to keep pressure on the tubing and block the flow of sanitizer. When the detector gets a signal it applies power to the solenoid, which pulls the plunger away from the tubing and allows sanitizer to flow. A warning similar to the first: you'll get much better results if activating the detector causes a short, fixed-duration pulse of power to the solenoid, and this will require more than just a few resistors.

If you're trying to use battery power, your job will get much harder. You'll need to figure a circuit which will only drive the LED occasionally (like once per second). And you'll need to learn how to make low-power solenoids, too. Commercial units such as found in airport rest rooms are quite sophisticated pieces of work.